# Function callback / Best Practices

Tags: swift, swift3

I am writing an API which load data for time intervals (startDate, endDate) from network and returns an image.

If there any incidence that my function (loadData) returns without executing success or failure callback?

In my case loadData simply returns if I am already loading data for this time intervals.

I think that it is not a good way.
Also I am asking myself for leak in this case.

EDIT: Here is my code:

```
func loadImageFromWebService(startDateISO8601: String, endDateISO8601: String, startCallback: (() -> Void)?, successCallback: ((UIImage?) -> Void)?, failureCallback: ((Error) -> Void)?) {

        let operationKey = makeOperationKey(forTimeIntervals: startDateISO8601, endDateISO8601)

        guard isOperationAlreadyLaunched(operationKey) == false else { return }

        startCallback?()

        let networkTask = WEB_SERVICE_MANAGER.getData(startDateISO8601: startDateISO8601, endDateISO8601: endDateISO8601, successCallback: { [ weak self ] data in

            let image = self?.makeImageWithData(data)
            successCallback?(image)

            }, // Success Callback
            failureCallback: { [ weak self ] error in
                self?.setNetworkTask(nil, forOperationKey: operationKey)
                failureCallback?(error)
            } // Failure Callback
        )

        self.setNetworkTask(networkTask, forOperationKey: operationKey)
    }
```

Do you have any advice?

Thanks

Comment: Don't talk about your code. _Show_ your code.

Answer (score 0):

Returning due to the "operation already being launched" is information the caller needs to know. Simply returning nothing and not calling either callback is a poor design. The caller has no idea why happened.

You have three options (pick one):

1. Call the success callback since there really wasn't a failure.
2. Call the failure callback with an "error" indicating that the failure is due to an "already launched" status.
3. Change the signature of your `loadImageFromWebService...` method to return a boolean. Return `false` to indicate you couldn't proceed since the operation is already in progress. Return `true` otherwise. This means if you return `false`, neither of the two callbacks will be called. If you return `true` then eventually one of the two callbacks will be called.